# Is it ok to say "to take the clothes onto the bed" to mean "to take the clothes from a certain place to the bed & then put them on the bed"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> [take](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/take_1?q=take) [transitive] to carry or move something from one place to another
>
> take something Remember to take your coat when you leave.
>
> take something with you I forgot to take my bag with me when I got
>   off the bus.
>
> take somebody something Shall I take my host family a gift?
>
> take something to somebody/something Can you take my suit to the
>   dry-cleaner's?
>
> You need to take your laptop to the technician.
>
> take something for somebody/something Don't forget to take a present
>   for Catherine's new baby.

---

> [put somebody/something + adv./prep.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/put?q=put) to cause somebody/something
>   to go to a particular place
>
> Her family put her into a nursing home.
>
> It was the year the Americans put a man on the moon.

---

Now, I want to express "**to take the clothes from a certain place to the bed & then put them on the bed**".

I am not sure it I can combine these 2 actions "**take**" & "**put**" into just one verb "**take**". For example, is it okay to say "**to take the clothes onto the bed**"?

However, we have to verb "**put**" which means "**to cause somebody/something to go to a particular place**".

I am not sure if "**to put the clothes on the bed**" means "**to take the clothes from a certain place to the bed & then put them on the bed**".

Comment: Are you talking about clothes for a person or for the bed?

Comment: You say "put the clothes on the bed". If you mean preparing the bed for use, for example wrapping a bottom sheet round the mattress and/or putting a cover onto a duvet, you would use the expression "make the bed".  The complete sentence would be "I got the bedclothes from the cupboard and made the bed".

Answer (score 1):

*Take onto the bed* would only work if you were to lie down on the bed while holding the clothes. You can, for example, take something onto a ship when you go aboard carrying it, but for placing something on a piece of furniture it has to be *take them to the bed and put them on it.*

Comment: but instead of saying "take them to the bed and put them on it", can I just say "put them on the bed" because "put" may mean "to cause something to a place"?

Comment: Yes, certainly you can.